# Series of children’s fantasy books young boy moves into a house with a barn and there's a silver magical spider

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to remember a book I read as a child but can only remember small details.  I am 38 so this would have been read when I was between the ages of 9-13.

The details I remember are a young boy he may have moved into a new house with a barn.  A magical spider, possibly silver like in color. He goes on a series of adventures.

Not a lot to go on I am afraid I know for certain it is not *Charlotte's Web*.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is "The Snow Spider." But can you remember anything else?

Comment: yep that is correct it is the snow spider, if you want to add it as an answer will give it a tick :)